# Use method of a different class in my form

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, class

Good day,

So, I have a class that converts arabic numerals to roman numerals. I have a loop that executes, if the user selected "Arabisch"(arabic) in the dropdownlist.
If the user selected "römisch"(roman) I want to do the same loop but convert the numerals to roman. In following you can see the code of the both classes. Whats the best way to initialize the method of the "ArabicToRoman" class in my loop to convert the numbers to roman?

```
namespace Friedhof_Generator
{
    class ArabicToRoman
    {
        private string[] Tausender = 
            { "", "M", "MM", "MMM" };
        private string[] Hunderter = 
            { "", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
        private string[] Zehner =
            { "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX" , "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
        private string[] Einer =
            { "", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

        private string ArabicRoman(int arabic)
        {
            if (arabic >= 4000)
            {
                int tausend = arabic / 1000;
                arabic %= 1000;
                return "(" + ArabicRoman(tausend) + ")" +
                    ArabicRoman(arabic);
            }

            string result = "";

            int num;
            num = arabic / 1000;
            result += Tausender[num];
            arabic %= 1000;

            num = arabic / 100;
            result += Hunderter[num];
            arabic %= 100;

            num = arabic / 10;
            result += Zehner[num];
            arabic %= 10;

            result += Einer[arabic];

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Above the ArabicToRoman class. Below the class with the loops.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Friedhof_Generator
{
    public partial class frm_Grabnummer : Form
    {
        public frm_Grabnummer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");
        }

        private void ddl_Feld_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int FeldVon, FeldBis, ReiheVon, ReiheBis, NrVon, NrBis;
            string Friedhof;

            FeldVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Feld.Text);
            FeldBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Feld.Text);
            ReiheVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Reihe.Text);
            ReiheBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Reihe.Text);
            NrVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Nr.Text);
            NrBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Nr.Text);
            Friedhof = tb_Friedhof.Text;

            if (ddl_Feld.Text == "Arabisch")
            {
                for (int iFeld = FeldVon; iFeld <= FeldBis; iFeld++)
                {
                    for (int iReihe = ReiheVon; iReihe <= ReiheBis; iReihe++)
                    {
                        for (int iNr = NrVon; iNr <= NrBis; iNr++)
                        {
                            lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Friedhof, iFeld, iReihe, iNr));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(ddl_Feld.Text == "Römisch")
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ArabicToRoman` class seems like a typical helper class, in days gone by you would just easily make it public and static

```
public static class ArabicToRoman
{
    private static string[] Tausender =  { "", "M", "MM", "MMM" };
    private static string[] Hunderter = { "", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
    private static string[] Zehner = { "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX" , "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
    private static string[] Einer = { "", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

    public static string Convert(int arabic)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Usage**

You can call this from anywhere that access to the assembly

```
ArabicToRoman.Convert(234);
```

---

You could also just make your classes and methods public

```
public class ArabicToRoman
{
    private string[] Tausender =  { "", "M", "MM", "MMM" };
    private string[] Hunderter = { "", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
    private string[] Zehner = { "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX" , "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
    private string[] Einer = { "", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

    public string Convert(int arabic)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Once again you call this anywhere that can access the assembly it lives in

```
var converter = new ArabicToRoman();
converter.Convert(345);
```

However these days, there is a big push for [Dependency Injection DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and Service architecture, You might make it a singleton Service and inject your converters. However this is debatable as well.

For your case and your level of understanding static classes or an instantiable class seem to be a good fit

---

**Further Reading**

[static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to
>   the type itself rather than to a specific object. The static modifier
>   can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators,
>   events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers,
>   finalizers, or types other than classes.

Comment: I like especially the "in days gone by.." part. Have an upvote ;)

Comment: @MongZhu *in days gone by* or fear the static police!

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the answer. I'll take time to get a better knowledge about that.^^